# How to use getAll(...) on ParseTreeMatch ANTLR4

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4

I have the following grammar :

```
input
: 
formula EOF
;

formula
:
TRUE                        
| FALSE                     
| formula AND formula       
| formula OR formula        
| (quantifier)+ ST condition        
;


condition
:
atom EQUALS QUOTE? (assignment | atom) QUOTE?
;

quantifier 
:
(FOREACH | EXISTS) variable IN domain 
;
.....
```

which parses simple first order logic formulas. So with the following code:

```
String formulaPatternString = "<formula>";
ParseTreePattern formulaPattern = parser.compileParseTreePattern(formulaPatternString, GraphParser.RULE_formula);
List<ParseTreeMatch> formulaMatches = formulaPattern.findAll(tree, "//formula");
```

I am finding the number of formulas found in my input. For Example

```
Exists node in GraphA -> node.color='red'
```

returns one `formulaMatch` and

```
Exists node in GraphA -> node.color='red' AND Foreach node in GraphA Exists node1 in GraphB -> node.color=node1.color
```

returns two `formulaMatches`.
Right now I want to use the `formulaMatches` in order to end up with the number of quantifiers in the formula (as you can see I am allowing one or more). I thought that the method I need is `formulaMatches.get(i).getAll("quantifier")` but this results in 0 matches (in my case the quantifier part in the first formula is `Exists node in GraphA` and in the second it is `Foreach node in GraphA Exists node1 in GraphB` which is 2 quantifiers). Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element of `formulaMatches` will be a `ParseTreeMatch` object that you can use to get the `ParseTree` corresponding to the `<formula>` placeholder in your pattern. That parse tree will be a `FormulaContext`. You can use the `quantifier()` method of `FormulaContext` to get the number of `QuantifierContext` children it has:

```
for (ParseTreeMatch match : formulaMatches) {
  int quantifierCount = ((FormulaContext)match.get("formula")).quantifier().size();
}
```

Note: if you are parsing using `ParserInterpreter`, your context objects will be [`InterpreterRuleContext`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java-master/org/antlr/v4/runtime/InterpreterRuleContext.html) instead of `FormulaContext`. In that case, you'll want to call the following:

```
for (ParseTreeMatch match : formulaMatches) {
  ParserRuleContext formulaContext = (FormulaContext)match.get("formula");
  int quantifierCount = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < formulaContext.getChildCount(); i++) {
    if (formulaContext.getChild(i) instanceof RuleNode
        && ((RuleNode)formulaContext.getChild(i)).getRuleContext().getRuleIndex()
            == RULE_quantifier)
    {
      quantifierCount++;
    }
  }

  // quantifierCount is accurate here...
}
```

Comment: hmm when I try to case a `ParseTreeMatch` to either `FormulaContext` or `ParseRuleContext` I end up with `incompatible types: ParseTreeMatch cannot be converted to ParserRuleContex` and `incompatible types: ParseTreeMatch cannot be converted to FormulaContext`

Comment: And one more question : how do I know whether I am parsing with `ParseInterpreter` or not?

Comment: I updated my post to correct the use of `ParseTreeMatch`. For such a trivial expression, you should be using the XPath expression `//formula` instead of a pattern, but either way works. You are using `ParserInterpreter` if you are using `ParserInterpreter` in your code.